# ASP.NET JavaScript Always Shows Default Alert Message

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Despite of JavaScript located in ASP.NET Core Page (cshtml), getting always a default message like "Changes Are Made..." from EDGE Browser (or CHROME is the same). Is there a way to use Custom Message?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function confirmExitPage() {
    event.preventDefault();
    return "My Custom Message I like to Show?";
}
```

I have already seen similar questions in SO, but none of them supplies a solution...

**EDIT**

Browsers absolutely prevent **User Custom Message**, reasonably. Then decide when this compulsory message should be issued to user:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="activateReloader()">activate</button>
    <button onclick="deactivateReloader()">deactivate</button>
    <script>
        function onBeforeUnload(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("my custom message");//this not works, for demo only
            e.returnValue = '';
        }

        function activateReloader() {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);
        }

        function deactivateReloader() {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This code states when message will be displayed to the user and when not.

Comment: Some browsers just don't allow custom messages

Comment: [Window: beforeunload event - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event): _"According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an event handler **should call `preventDefault()` on the event.**"_

Comment: problem is this: alert message is required when a condition exists.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks, tried `event.preventDefault()` but still same message **Changes you made may not be saved.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was prohibited in browsers a long time ago (Chrome 51 is from 2016). You can't show a custom message anymore.

> Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38, and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#compatibility_notes

Reading the issue on the Chromium issue tracker it was about avoiding bad sites using it to try scamming users.

> onbeforeunload dialogs are used for two things on the Modern Web:
>
> 1. Preventing users from inadvertently losing data.
> 2. Scamming users.
>
> In an attempt to restrict their use for the latter while not stopping the former, we are going to not display the string provided by the webpage.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587940

Comment: thanks, is it possible to active (and kill) a `JavaScript` when a special situation arises, this way `default message` would be meaningful?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can run some scripts in `beforeunload` but you can't show your own dialogs (like alert or prompt) and there is no way to change the default message.

Comment: trying to prevent user from leaving page is necessary only when some events occur, so how I activate (or create\kill) `onbeforeunload` when this event occurs (then I would have no problem with MS Default Message)?

Comment: Oh, just don't setup the event before it is needed. Use `addEventListener` to register the event and then call `removeEventListener` if you need to remove it again.

Comment: thanks, tried it and get what I need, please see my editon on question.